# Using Array in TypeScript Model (NativeScript)

Tags: typescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm trying to create a model called "UploadItem" that contains a field that is an array of media items (aka "MediaItems").  The idea here is to create an upload package in NativeScript / TypeScript with meta information that can have one or more images/videos attached to this upload package.

I'm getting an error stating that "Type 'MediaItem" is not assignable to type 'MediaItem[]'".

**Model Code (individual image / video)**
./services/upload.media.model.ts

```
export class MediaItem {
  constructor(
    public id?: number,
    public name?: string, 
    public type?: string,
    public mediaURL?: string,
    public mediaFile?: File,
    public thumb?: HTMLImageElement
    ) { }
}
```

**Parent Model Code (Upload Item for metadata, includes Array of Items)**
./services/upload.model.ts

```
import { MediaItem } from "./upload.media.model";

export class UploadItem {
  constructor(
    public mediaItems: Array<MediaItem>, // Change from comment by @Raven
    public id?: number,
    public name?: string, 
    public description?: string, 
    public title?: string, 
    public text?: string,         
    public selected?: boolean,
    public status?: string
    ) { }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you initializing an `UploadItem` anywhere with a single `MediaItem` object instead of an array of `MediaItem` objects?

Comment: Also `mediaItems` is a required parameter and must precede optional parameters. Possibly a typo in your example.

Comment: @Raven - the problem was the required parameter.  I updated the question to reflect that, but we decided to abandon the sub-array since we are using Firebase as a backend and retrieving data differently. ;)